# Do all IgG autoantibodies lead to autoimmune diseases?

Tags: autoimmune

If there is a presence of autoantibody in our blood, does that mean that we are going to have an autoimmune disease? Are there some autoantibodies which don't cause tissue and organ damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual with biology, it's not that simple. There are autoantibodies present even in people without any signs of autoimmune disease. The immune system is a complex network of positive and negative regulatory cells and molecules - looking at a single component is unlikely to determine the state of the system. This is a major reason that it has been so difficult to figure out how to selectively act on the immune system to stop or prevent an autoimmune disease without compromising normal immune function.

Here's an article that expands on some of these aspects: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2703183/

For example, note "Despite the physiological elimination (negative selection) or functional inactivation (anergy) of high-affinity, self-reactive T and B lymphocytes in the thymus and bone marrow, respectively, there is compelling evidence that low-affinity, potentially autoreactive cells persist and that low-affinity reactivity to self-antigens is required for survival of T and probably B lymphocytes in the peripheral immune system."

It's also important to keep in mind that affinity of Abs and receptors for antigens usually depends on additional 3rd party molecules involved in the interaction, and that a single molecule may present very differently in different situations (for example, damage or inflammation may alter some self molecules into a previously unseen configuration that stimulates self-reactivity).

Comment: Can you please add some citations to support your claims?

Comment: @MattDMo hope that helps a bit

Comment: That's a good reference for autoantibodies in general, but the original question asked specifically about IgG, which as far as I know are always associated with pathology. I suggest expanding on that, talking more about normal IgM autoantibodies and what their suspected roles may be, then talk about class switching and IgGs being essentially universally associated with disease of some sort. You have the beginnings of a good answer, though.

Comment: Yes, I interpreted the question as being very basic and not intended specifically about IgG based on the body of the question. I don't have a good feel here yet about how deep to go in a response -- thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understand that IgM autoantibodies undergoes class switching to IgG and becomes more specific for the target antigen. Does having IgG autoantibodies indicate that at some point in future, the person is going to develop an autoimmune disease?

Comment: @Riq generally, yes. In fact, they likely have already developed disease, as it is during that process that class-switching occurs.